# How to provide a mock instance to an injected class member

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am creating unit tests using JUnit 4 and mockito. I encountered a problem when trying to provide a mock instance for one of the class members.

Here's the class to be tested:

```
public class FeedbackServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {
  @Reference
  private ConfigService configService;

  @Override
  protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) {
    FeedbackData feedbackData = extractFeedbackData(request.getRequestParameterMap());

    try {
      boolean isEmailSent = configService.send(feedbackData);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      ...
    }
  }

  private FeedbackData extractFeedbackData(RequestParameterMap data) {
    String firstName = data.getValue(ParamKey.FIRST_NAME.toString()).getString();
    String email = data.getValue(ParamKey.EMAIL.toString()).getString();
    String message = data.getValue(ParamKey.MESSAGE.toString()).getString();
    String contactNumber = data.getValue(ParamKey.CONTACT_NUMBER.toString()).getString();

    return new FeedbackData(firstName, email, message, contactNumber);
  }
}
```

When I try to use `configService.send(feedbackData)`, the test produces a `NullPointerException`. Now I tried to Inject the missing value in the test class:

```
public class FeedbackServletTest extends Mockito {
  @InjectMocks
  private ConfigService configService = mock(ConfigService.class);

  @Test
  public void testDoPost() throws Exception {
    ...
    when(configService.send(new FeedbackData("Nikola", "nikola.tesla@genius.co", "Our virtues and our failings are inseparable, like force and matter." +
            "When they separate, man is no more.", "09991234567"))).thenCallRealMethod();
    ...
  }
}
```

I tried to re-run the tests but the NPE is still there.

How can this be done properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@InjectMocks annotation should be placed on an object instance You want to test.

```
@Mock
ConfigService mockedConfigService;

@InjectMocks
FeedbackServlet tested = new FeedbackServlet();
```